# The proof of the Hilbert-Burch theorem

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

I am reading the proof of Theorem 1.4.17 (Hilbert-Burch theorem) in *Cohen-Macaulay Rings* by Bruns & Herzog.

**My question**

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring, and $\varphi\colon R^n \to R^{n+1}$ an $R$-homomorphism such that the $n$-th ideal of minors $I_n (\varphi)$ satisfies $\operatorname{grade} I_n (\varphi) \geq 2$. Let $\pi\colon R^{n + 1}\to R$ be an $R$-homomorphism which sends $e_i$ to $(-1)^{i}\delta_i$ where $\delta_i$ is the $i$-minor of $\varphi$ with the $i$-th row deleted. Then, I believe it should be proven that $\operatorname{grade} I_1 (\pi)\geq 1$, or alternatively $\pi$ has rank $1$ i.e. the localization  $(\operatorname{Im}\pi)\otimes Q$ (where $Q = \operatorname{Frac}R$) is free $Q$-module of rank $1$. How to prove this ?

**Backgrounds.**

In the situation above, the Hilbert-Burch theorem asserts that the complex
$$
0 \to R^{n}\to R^{n + 1}\to R\to 0
$$
where $R^{n}\to R^{n + 1}$ is $\varphi$, and $R^{n + 1}\to R$ is $\pi$, is acyclic. This acyclicity allegedly follows from the Buchsbaum-Eisenbud acyclicity criterion. To apply the acyclicity criterion, it should be proven that $\operatorname{grade} I_n (\varphi) \geq 2$ and $\operatorname{grade} I_1 (\pi)\geq 1$. The former follows from the hypothesis, so the problem is the latter. By 1.4.11, it suffices to show that $\pi$ has rank $1$. How to prove this ?

Comment: $I_1(\pi)$ and $I_n(\varphi)$ are by definition both generated by all the $n\times n$ minors of  the $(n+1)\times n$ matrix of $\varphi$.

Comment: Oops, it's trivial. Thanks.